# Error Propagations for Integrals and Summations

Tags: error-analysis, calculus

Suppose I have 3 straight lines:

$$y_1 = m_1 x + c_1;$$

$$y_2 = m_2 x + c_2;$$

$$y_3 = m_3 x + c_3;,$$

and

$$m_1 = 1 \pm 1.1, c_1 = 1 \pm 1.11,$$

$$m_2 = 2 \pm 2.2, c_2 = 2 \pm 2.22,$$

$$m_3 = 3 \pm 3.3, c_3 = 3 \pm 3.33.$$

Then integrate $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$ w.r.t. $x$ for $x = (0,5)$ and label them as $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ respectively. i.e.

$$I_1 = m_1 \frac{x^2}{2} + c_1 x = 17.5\pm??$$

$$I_2 = m_2 \frac{x^2}{2} + c_2 x = 35\pm??$$

$$I_3 = m_3 \frac{x^2}{2} + c_3 x = 52.5\pm??$$

$$BigI = I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 105\pm??$$

How do I find the error / uncertainty for "BigI"? i.e. Find ?? for "BigI"

Comment: Your $m_i$ and $c_i$ are almost certainly correlated which means you can't apply the simple combination of  errors formula.  You can avoid this by refitting using $y=m(x-\overline x)+c'$ as those $m$ and $c'$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Restating your question, you are asking how a variable $A$  is effected by the uncertainties of its multiple parameters, $A(p_1, p_2, \ldots)$. If the parameters are independent there exist simple equations. Have you looked into this topic? E.g. if you consider only $y_1(m_1, c_1)$, do you know how to calculate the uncertainty, if $m_1$ and $c_1$ are uncorrelated? In the current form I simply can not see how answering your question would help others. However, this is the goal of SE.